Can I apply sealant over wooden expansion joints?
My driveway has 3/4" strips of wood in the expansion joints of the concrete.
Can I apply a polyurethane sealant (Sikaflex) or a silane polyether sealant (Rapidset) directly on top of the wood?
Asking because I believe the wood is nailed into place and is difficult to remove. I'm just not sure if I need to be worried about the wood rotting or settling or if the sealant would help prevent that from being an issue.

Is it actually wood, or simply pressed fiber material?

I don't know for sure, but it appears to have a grain like wood.

Assuming the wood is pressure treated for ground contact it should last about 50 years
After that there may begin to be a gap in your driveway. I suspect you will be able to drive over this gap, but it may pose a hazard for roller-skaters and cyclists.
